# Hold TcpClient Connection with WCF

Tags: wcf, hosting, tcpclient

Hallo
 I need a Tcp connection to a server alive in backgrond and applications will send data with this connection.I searched around and found WCF singleton is apporiate for this task
here is a code snippet that i use below
my question is that the good way and any problem can be with this?

```
 string hostAddress = string.Empty;
           try
            {
                srvHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ControllerClass));
                NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
                netTcpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;
                netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel =      System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None;
                netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;

                srvHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IControllerContract), netTcpBinding, hostAddress);
                srvHost.Credentials.WindowsAuthentication.AllowAnonymousLogons = true;

                ServiceThrottlingBehavior serviceThrottlingBehavior = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
                serviceThrottlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1000;
                serviceThrottlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentInstances = 1000;
                serviceThrottlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentSessions = 1000;
                srvHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceThrottlingBehavior);
                srvHost.Open();
            }
            catch (System.TimeoutException timeoutEx)
            {

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                ReOpenHostConnection();//initialize again Controller Class
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("cannot start Service Ex:{0}", ex.ToString()), TraceEventType.Error.ToString());
            }

//Controller Class Initialize Code Snippet

TcpClient iTcpClient = new TcpClient();
                iTcpClient.Connect(serverIP, serverPort);
                networkStream = iTcpClient.GetStream();
                aSychDataByte = new byte[iTcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                networkStream.BeginRead(aSychDataByte, 0, incommTcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize, ReadAsych, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you combine TcpClient with WCF? If you need low level Tcp communication build client and server based on low level Tcp classes. If you need service and you don't bother with message formats use WCF.

For your problem. You don't need singleton. You just need the connection to be opened. For this you need to create WCF proxy instance (open channel) on the client and call the service. It will create connection to service instance wich will live until you close the client proxy, until your service host stops working or until timeout (10 minutes of client inactivity by default).

Comment: I connect to a 3rd party tcp server.Firstly connection start i send a start command and this shoıld be alive all time and client applications will send data over this connection on a singleton wcf service

Comment: And are you sure that your code uses that connection you manually started?

Comment: i open and hold tcp connection to 3rd party server with tcpclient object on wcf singleton procedures the tcpclient object is used..